# Initialization of field image and price

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I got this error when I run the app.
while I think I wrote the codes properly.
I'll give the codes all in the link bellow.
and for the picture is the same.

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtjgC.png)

and here is the link of the codes..

[codes](https://codeshare.io/JbWDyK)

Comment: Can you please include an image of the full error by taking a screenshot of the error printed in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this line in your code

```dart
late final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _Key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

You don't need to use the `late` keyword when you assign a value to your variable. The `late` keyword is used when you don't want to assign a value to your non-nullable variable but you won't use that variable before you initialize it `later`

Try removing the `late` keyword

```dart
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _Key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Regarding your first 2 `late` variables, I don't see them used anywhere in the code. If you want them provided from outside the widget then you should pass them as params and initialize them in your widget's constructor like so:

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final int color;
  final String name;
  
  HomeScreen({
    required this.color, 
    required this.name,
  });
  
  //...
}
```

Now you can pass them like so

```dart
HomeScreen(color: 0xffffffff, name: 'foo'),
```